# Object attribute exists but returns undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have a custom class/object in a script. In one of the object methods, when I run the following commands:

```
MapLabel.prototype.show = function()
{
    console.log(this);         // Here are the
    console.log(this.canvas);  // lines in question

    if (!this.canvas) // this is not giving the expected result
    {
        console.log('canvas doesnt exist to show');
        return;
    }

    console.log('showing maplabel');
    this.visible = true;

    this.canvas.style['visibility'] = 'visible';
    this.marker.setVisible(true);
}
```

I get the following:

```
MapLabel {gm_accessors_: Object, fontFamily: "'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 
Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif", gm_bindings_: Object, fontSize: 14, fontColor: "#FFFFFF"…}
__e3_: Object
align: "center"
canvas: <canvas>
fontColor: "#FFFFFF"
fontFamily: "'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
fontSize: 14
gm_accessors_: Object
gm_bindings_: Object
gm_props_: Hu
id: 216
map: xh
marker: Ah
markerImage: Qh.MarkerImage
minZoom: 5
position: Q
strokeColor: "#000000"
strokeWeight: 4
text: "Sometext"
visible: false
zIndex: 100
__proto__: Dh

undefined    // <---- this.canvas = undefined even though it exists?
```

You can see in the output that `this.canvas` exists and has a value. But when `console.log(this.canvas)` is run immediately afterwords, it returns `undefined`.

Is there something I'm missing here?

**Updated: I added the function that the code is being called in**

Comment: Show some code. Something sounds out of scope possibly.

Comment: updated with the classes method that the code is being run in.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but it looks like everything from `_e3_` down is not part of MapLabel. I would expect all of that stuff to be within the `{}`

Comment: Well the `...` at the end of the {} is just what Chrome dev tools spits out cause it doesn't want to list everything. It's not until I expand it that it shows all the attributes in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2):

Just a wild guess, but the "problem" could be with the Chrome console. When you output the `this` context into the debugger, the console shows the **current** value at the time of inspecting, not at the time of execution.

[Take a look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qxds/). When you click the button, you'll see this in the console:

```
The current value is: {"hello":"world"} 
The this context is > Thing {hello: "world"} 
changing value of this.hello... 
The current value is: {"hello":"Cleveland"}
```

Now open the object inspector by clicking the arrow in front of `> Thing {hello: "world"}`, and you'll see:

```
The current value is: {"hello":"world"} 
The this context is  Thing {hello: "world"}
  hello: "Cleveland"                              <-- Surprise!
  test: function () {
  __proto__: Thing
changing value of this.hello... 
The current value is: {"hello":"Cleveland"}
```

In which case `this.canvas` really *is* undefined at the time of execution.

To make sure, you can `console.log(this.canvas)` instead.